# How to install package from older repo

Tags: 12.04

I want to install for example http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/window-picker-applet

Answer (score 0):

Not going to happen. That package has been discontinued after Natty and the core of Ubuntu has changed to something different.

Have a look at CCSM's scale plugin for a possible alternative:

[image]

Comment: But that plugin was for Ubuntu netbook remix core..